# Lazy loading element in typescript hook not working

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, next.js, lazy-loading

I've implemented a lazy loading hook, but for some reason the carousel component is not loading at all. I've got it from here: https://betterprogramming.pub/lazy-loading-in-next-js-simplified-435681afb18a

This is my child that I want to render when it's in view:

```
import { useRef } from "react";
import Carousel from "../components/carousel";
import useOnScreen from "../hooks/useOnScreen";

// home page
function HomePage() {
  const carouselRef = useRef();
  const carouselRefValue = useOnScreen(carouselRef);
  return (
        <div className="snap-y">
          {/* 1 */}
          <div className="flex justify-center items-start relative min-h-[calc(100vh_-_5rem)] bg-black snap-start ">
            {/* Cone */}
            <div className="absolute w-full max-w-full overflow-hidden min-w-fit cone animate-wiggle"></div>
    
            <div className="grid justify-center grid-cols-4 max-w-7xl">
//Content
          </div>
    
          {/* 2 */}
          <div className="z-20 pb-4 bg-black snap-start" ref={carouselRef.current}>
            {carouselRefValue && <Carousel />}
          </div>
    
          {/* 3 */}
          <div className="flex items-start justify-center py-32 min-h-fit bg-slate-50 snap-start">
           //More content
        </div>
      );
    }

export default HomePage;
```

useOnScreen hook:

```js
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
const useOnScreen = (ref: any) => {
  const [isIntersecting, setIntersecting] = useState(false);
  useEffect(() => {
    const observer = new IntersectionObserver(([entry]) => setIntersecting(entry.isIntersecting));
    if (ref.current) {
      observer.observe(ref.current);
    }
  }, []);
  return isIntersecting;
};
export default useOnScreen;
```

Edit: Needed to add `const carouselRef = useRef() as React.MutableRefObject<HTMLInputElement>;` paired with @asynts's answer.

Comment: What is "not working" is it not loaded, even when it's on screen? Please be more specific.

Comment: @asynts edited. the second (carousel) component is not rendering at all

Comment: Do you receive any errors in the console?

Comment: @asynts none at all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is incorrect:

```
<div className="z-20 pb-4 bg-black snap-start" ref={carouselRef.current}></div>
```

it should be:

```
<div className="z-20 pb-4 bg-black snap-start" ref={carouselRef}></div>
```

Comment: I get the error: Type 'MutableRefObject<undefined>' is not assignable to type 'LegacyRef<HTMLDivElement> | undefined'.
  Type 'MutableRefObject<undefined>' is not assignable to type 'RefObject<HTMLDivElement>'.
    Types of property 'current' are incompatible.
      Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'HTMLDivElement | null'.ts(2322)
index.d.ts(137, 9): The expected type comes from property 'ref' which is declared here on type 'DetailedHTMLProps<HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement>, HTMLDivElement>'

Comment: Put that in the question please and also provide information where exactly this error occurs.

Comment: I fixed it. const carouselRef = useRef() as React.MutableRefObject<HTMLInputElement>